# listview android: add and remove item simultaneously

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

After hours of searching, I cannot find anyone who has the similar problem as mine, could you kindly support me for this problem, please.

I have an activity with two listview: listview1 is placed above listview2.

### What I need to do now is whenever user touches to an item on a listview, that item will be removed from current listview, and will be displayed on the other listvew.

This is my activity:

```
private ListView mListApplication_kid, mListApplication_non_kid;
private List<ResolveInfo> mListAplicationInfo;
private List<MyApplication> mListApplicationList = new ArrayList<MyApplication>();
private List<MyApplication> mListApplicationList_non_kid = new ArrayList<MyApplication>();
private KidModeAdapter1 mAplicationAdapter;
private KidModeAdapter2 mAplicationAdapter_non_default;
private Context mContext;
private String TAG = "KidModeActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kid_mode);
    mContext=this;
    list_kid_mode =  new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(PHONE, CONTACTS, MESSAGE, CAMERA, CHROME));
    mListApplication_kid = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_kidmode_default);
    mListApplication_non_kid = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_kidmode_non_default);
    loadAplication();
}
private void loadAplication() {
    mAplicationAdapter = new KidModeAdapter1(mContext, R.layout.aplication_item, mListApplicationList);
    mAplicationAdapter_non_default = new KidModeAdapter2(mContext, R.layout.aplication_item, mListApplicationList_non_kid);
    mListApplicationList.removeAll(mListApplicationList);
    mListApplicationList_non_kid.removeAll(mListApplicationList_non_kid);
    mAplicationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mAplicationAdapter_non_default.notifyDataSetChanged();
    new loadKidMode().execute(); // load all the available MyApplication into the mListApplicationList, and mListApplicationList_non_kid
    mListApplication_kid.setAdapter(mAplicationAdapter);
    mListApplication_non_kid.setAdapter(mAplicationAdapter_non_default);
}
```

and this is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtKidMode"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/default_mode"
    android:textColor="@color/title"
    android:textSize="@dimen/title_textsize" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_kidmode_default"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/counter_text_color"
    android:clickable="true">
</ListView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_kidmode_non_default"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@color/list_background" 
    android:clickable="true">
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I know it is about this activity and setting up the KidModeAdapter1 and KidModeAdapter2 files, but just don't know how.
Could you kindly help me, please !!!

Answer (score 1):

You should set `OnItemClickListener` to the `ListView` that you want to click:

```
mListApplication_kid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

         mListApplicationList_non_kid.add(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
         mAplicationAdapter_non_default.notifyDataSetChanged();
         mListApplicationList.remove(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
         mApplicationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

 }
});
```

This will remove the item from one `ListView` and insert the same item in the other `ListView` when the item is clicked.

**EDIT**

If you have other elements which request focus in your list item, add `android:focusable="false"` to them

Comment: thank you, I have applied that, but there's no log for aaaaaaaaa as below:

Comment: thank you. I have tried your solution and put inside the onItemClick() a log comment to check, but it runs without going into the onItemtClick, as the log does not show.
Could you please guide me more.
thank you !!

Comment: This is what I have applied:
  mListApplication_kid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
          long id) {
           System.out.println("aaaaaaaaaa");
           mListApplicationList_non_kid.add((MyApplication) parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
           mAplicationAdapter_non_default.notifyDataSetChanged();
           mListApplicationList.remove(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
           mAplicationAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
  });

Comment: Ok, make sure your list is `clickable` by setting `android:clickable="true"` in your xml

Comment: after adding android:clickable="true" and check again, still no log "aaaaaa" showing.

Comment: How is the xml for the list item? Can you update your question with the edited code along with the list item xml, please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70064/discussion-between-zoro-and-vinitius).